# Showing Validation Error like a popup,instead of loading another page in Django

Tags: python, django, validation

[image: I just like the way django displays an error message like this]

I have also created a simple registration form for a blog asking for Username and Registration Name from the user.
When  enter an invalid entry for the Registration Number django, by default redirects me to page displaying the object could not be created because the data could not be validated.
Instead of redirecting to that page, how do I display "Invalid registration Number" in a similar popup.

My `views.py`:

```
def post_new(request,):
if request.method=="POST":
    authorform=NewAuthor(request.POST)
    form=NewPost(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and authorform.is_valid():
        new_post=form.save(commit=False)
        new_author=authorform.save(commit=False)
        new_post.published_date=timezone.now()
        new_author.save()
        new_post.author=new_author
        new_post.save()
        return redirect('post_detail',pk=new_post.id)
else:
    form=NewPost()
    authorform=NewAuthor()
    return render(request,'justablog/post_new.html',{'form':form,'authorform':authorform})
```

My `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
class Author(models.Model):
    Username=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    RegNo=models.CharField(max_length=9,validators=[RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^[0-9]{2}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{4}',
        message=("Invalid Registration Number"),
        code='invalid_regno'
),])
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Username+'('+self.RegNo+')'
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author,null=True)
    published_date=models.DateTimeField(blank=True,null=True)
    def publish(self):
        self.published_date=timezone.now()
        self.author.save()
        self.save()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My `forms.py`;

```
class NewPost(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Post
        fields=('title','body',)
class NewAuthor(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Author
        fields=('Username','RegNo',)
```

My form while adding a user whose registration number is incorrect looks like this:

[image]

My error trace back page:

[image]

My post_new.html:

```
{% extends 'justablog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Add a new post</h1>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
{{ authorform.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Could you please show the entire error trace log, normally you should not be redirected when you form is invalid

Comment: added images of the trace log

Comment: I have posted an answer for your trace log, try fixing the bug and then I'll try to help with your popup window as well

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your view code. You check if form is valid, but you do not check if the authorform is also valid. So django is complaining that you are trying so save the authorform without first validating it. Your if statement should check if both forms are valid.

Edit:
Now the front-end, to answer your original question.

You probably want to render the form manually, in stead of using form.as_p. You can loop over the various fields of the form, and display the errors for each field like so:

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="popup">
    {{ field.errors }}
    </div>
    {{ field.label_tag }} 
    {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

So you put the field.errors in your popup window, and on page reload you check in your frontend code if there are any errors present. If there are errors, you display the popup window.

This should get you started I think

Comment: Added the if statement you requested @dentemm